# Muting an embedded YouTube video without using SWFObject

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

It seems from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Requirements): that using a `SWFObject` is optional. Since I have a simple requirement (- only to mute a video), I tried the following code, but `onYouTubePlayerReady` doesn't get called at all (-I put an `alert` there and it never fired).

What's missing from this code?

```
<iframe id="id1" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/shbgRyColvE?version=3;enablejsapi=1" allowscriptaccess="true" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, you're using the iframe Player, which is good—it's newer than the Flash-only player (which is where `SWFObject` comes into play) and it's what we recommend for new development.

If you want to make API calls against the iframe Player, you need to initialize things a bit differently, though. You can follow the example at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

and modify the `onPlayerReady` event handler in that example to explicitly mute the player, i.e.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.mute();
  // Anything else you want to do, like start playback...
}
```